# File Watcher script

Tags: powershell

I am writing a file watcher Powershell script for two FTP directories. The plan is to have an email sent when a file gets created, which I have working. Additionally, the users want to also have an alert sent if no files are sent within a specific time interval.
Is that even possible with the register event command?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#File Watcher 2014 
#This script is used for FTP purposes to watch files for a specific directory and alerts when a file is created and to alert when a file has not been sent

$folder = 'C:\TEST' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
$filter = '*.txt.gpg'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 
# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 

# Here is the file created event: 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 

$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
Out-File -FilePath C:\TEST\Logs\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"} 
Send-MailMessage -To  -From  -Subject "" -Body   -SmtpServer  

#This part will alert if no files have been found after last Create Time
    for($i=-4,$i -lt 0,$i++){
    $start = (get-date -hour 2).adddays($i);
    $end = (get-date -hour 3).adddays($i);
    {}
Else
Send-MailMessage -To  -From  -Subject  -Body  -SmtpServer 
{}
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? Where are you stuck? What (if any) errors are you getting?

Comment: You have a for loop that is using ',' instead of ';' That won't work. Can you clarify the question. Are you supposed to get an alert if no files are created withing, say, 1 hour? Or do you mean to alert if no files are generated, say between 1am and 2am?

Comment: I was looking to write a script to send an alert if files are created within a time frame and an alert if no files are created within that same time frame.